# Passing integer as gpointer in g_signal_connect

Tags: c, gtk3

I tried finding a similar question, but couldn't find any solutions.

I have a piece of software written in C using GTK3, and I'm trying to rig up a callback for a button press on my GUI. The code is supposed to pass an integer as an argument to let my callback function know which GUI window to reference.

```
void main_gui()
{
    int number = 5;

    g_signal_connect(button,
                    "clicked",
                    G_CALLBACK(callback_func),
                    (gpointer*) &num);
}

void callback_func(gpointer *data)
{
    int number;
    number = (int*)data;
    printf("Number: %d\n", number);
}
```

The problem is whenever I try to cast the number to an integer and check the number (via print statement), it returns an incorrect number.

Comment: or make `number` an `int*` and dereference it in `printf`

Comment: Neither of these worked unfortunately

Comment: Where did you find the prototype for your signal handler? For a GTK button the "clicked" event should look like [this](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkButton.html#GtkButton-clicked) This manual is a good source for all callback signature.

Answer (score 1):

First, does that function actually take a `gpointer*` or just a `gpointer`?  The latter seems more likely, since `gpointer` is a `void *`.

Second, you're passing the address of a local variable `&number` rather than its value.  Don't do that.  The local variable is on the stack and will likely not exist once your function exits (which happens before your callback is called).  Just pass the value cast as the required type:  `(gpointer)number`  Then when you want to use it, cast it back:  `(int)data`

Here's the updated code:

```
void main_gui()
{
    int number = 5;

    g_signal_connect(button,
                    "clicked",
                    G_CALLBACK(callback_func),
                    //(gpointer*) &num);
                    (gpointer)number);
}

//void callback_func(gpointer *data)
void callback_func(gpointer data)
{
    int number;
    //number = (int*)data;
    number = (int)data;

    printf("Number: %d\n", number);
}
```

Comment: glib provides two helpful macros: `GINT_TO_POINTER` and `GPOINTER_TO_INT`

Comment: I tried your solutions, even with the macro, and I'm still printing out what looks like an address in memory rather than my number 5. Would I just use the macro like `number = GPOINTER_TO_INT(data)`?

Comment: Please paste your updated code as an addendum to your question.

Comment: your callback function is missing an argument it should be 

" void callback_func (GtkButton *button, gpointer   data)"

Comment: @SivaGuru That's exactly what the issue was! Because I was missing the extra argument, stuff in memory was all funky. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have got two errors, it should be **(gpointer) &number** in main_gui and **number = *((int*)data)** in callback_func. I would also do **static int number = 5**:

```
void main_gui()
{
    static int number = 5;

    g_signal_connect(button,
                    "clicked",
                    G_CALLBACK(callback_func),
                    (gpointer) &number);
}

void callback_func(gpointer *data)
{
    int number;
    number = *((int*)data);
    printf("Number: %d\n", number);
}
```